# What bug is this in my closet

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I keep finding these little insects on my clothes in the one corner of my closet. They seem to be a mm in length. I’ve never seen them walk and I’ve only seen one in any given time. I’ve never seen hairy projections so it makes me want to rule out carpet beetles since the photos online show some hair. Tonight I found one on my fabric headboard. They seem light brown with black stripes.  Thoroughly disgusted. [

1. [image]
2. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Hairy projections are only really found on the larvae of the carpet beetles.

The adult beetles look like beetles - which this almost certainly is.

Probably [varied carpet beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle)

[image]
Image attribution: Staff of York Museums Trust, CC BY-SA 4.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0, via Wikimedia Commons